# How dynamicaly setText of textview in fragment in FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, settext, fragmentstatepageradapter

i want setText of my TextView in fragment of a FragmentStateAdapter in a viewPager when he was created(or page are loaded). I test with a setOnPageChangeListener but it's don't work, so have you idea to how doing this. Bellow my adaptater and how i tried two use the setOnPageChangeListener, (if i can initialize my field when the fragment is created, it will be pretty good).

mytest :

```
.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                    pdate=(TextView)myPager.getChildAt(arg0).findViewById(R.id.txtPagerDate);
                    pdate.setText(nextDay.get(arg0).get(KEY_DATE).toString());
                    pmaxmin=(TextView)myPager.getChildAt(arg0).findViewById(R.id.txtPagerMaxMin);
                    pmaxmin.setText("MAX: "+nextDay.get(arg0).get(KEY_HIGH).toString()+"° | Min: "+nextDay.get(arg0).get(KEY_LOW).toString()+"°");
                    pprecip=(TextView)myPager.getChildAt(arg0).findViewById(R.id.txtPagerPrecipitations);
                    pprecip.setText("Précipitation: "+nextDay.get(arg0).get(KEY_PRECIPAMOUNT).toString()+" mm");
                    pvent=(TextView)myPager.getChildAt(arg0).findViewById(R.id.txtPagerVent);
                    pvent.setText("Vent: "+nextDay.get(arg0).get(KEY_WINDSPEED).toString()+" Km/h - "+nextDay.get(arg0).get(KEY_WINDDIRECTION).toString());
                    pneige=(TextView)myPager.getChildAt(arg0).findViewById(R.id.txtPagerNeige);
                    pneige.setText("Neige: "+nextDay.get(arg0).get(KEY_SNOWAMOUNT).toString()+" mm");
                    pweatherIcn=(ImageView)myPager.getChildAt(arg0).findViewById(R.id.imgPagerTemps);
                    pweatherIcn.setImageDrawable(drawable2);
                }
            });
```

ViewPagerAdapterBis.java

```
package base.appliMeteo.basemeteo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class ViewPagerAdapterBis extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


    static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> nextDay=MainMeteo.nextDay;


    public ViewPagerAdapterBis(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new ViewPagerAdapterObject();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        // Our object is just an integer :-P
        args.putInt(ViewPagerAdapterObject.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 7;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
    }


}
```

ViewPageAdapterObject.java

```
package base.appliMeteo.basemeteo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ViewPagerAdapterObject extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meteo_pager, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to use a Handler in this case

Comment: I've tried several method with Handler, but any worked and i don't really understand how worked Handler method :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the solutions i've made, it worked well

ViewPagerAdapterBis.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapterBis extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    static int x;
    public ViewPagerAdapterBis(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        x=i;
        Fragment fragment = new ViewPagerAdapterObject();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        // Our object is just an integer :-P
        args.putInt(ViewPagerAdapterObject.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 7;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        if(object != null){
            return ((Fragment)object).getView() == view;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }



}
```

ViewPagerAdapterObject.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapterObject extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    TextView pdate;
    TextView pvent;
    TextView phumidite;
    TextView pmaxmin;
    TextView pprecip;
    TextView pneige;
    ImageView pweatherIcn;

    int x=ViewPagerAdapterBis.x;

    static final String KEY_DAY="day";
    static final String KEY_DAYTIME="daytime";
    static final String KEY_DATE="obsdate";
    static final String KEY_HIGH="hightemperature";
    static final String KEY_LOW="lowtemperature";
    static final String KEY_PRECIPAMOUNT="precipamount";
    static final String KEY_SNOWAMOUNT="snowamount";
    static final String KEY_WINDSPEED="windspeed";
    static final String KEY_WINDDIRECTION="winddirection";

    static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> nextDay=MainMeteo.nextDay;
    static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> nextDayJourney=MainMeteo.nextDayJourney;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meteo_pager, container, false);

        pdate=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textPagerDateBis);
        pdate.setText(nextDay.get(x).get(KEY_DATE).toString());
        pmaxmin=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtPagerMaxMin);
        pmaxmin.setText("MAX: "+nextDayJourney.get(x).get(KEY_HIGH).toString()+"° | Min: "+nextDayJourney.get(x).get(KEY_LOW).toString()+"°");
        pprecip=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtPagerPrecipitations);
        pprecip.setText("Précipitation: "+nextDay.get(x).get(KEY_PRECIPAMOUNT).toString()+" mm");
        pvent=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtPagerVent);
        pvent.setText("Vent: "+nextDay.get(x).get(KEY_WINDSPEED).toString()+" Km/h - "+nextDay.get(x).get(KEY_WINDDIRECTION).toString());
        pneige=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtPagerNeige);
        pneige.setText("Neige: "+nextDay.get(x).get(KEY_SNOWAMOUNT).toString()+" mm");

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I just take the item number in my adaptater and give it to my fragment for call the matching value.